# Pass ContentEditable values into array

Tags: php, html, arrays, contenteditable

I'm passing the contents of my HTML table into an array so that i can later pass the PHP to post to a different table, but i'm getting stuck, i have an editable column that keeps reverting to its original value (0) when i click the button that fires the javascript array code, i want to be able to filter out the items left at 0 from the array so i need the edited values to stay and get pushed into the array. Does anyone know why they keep resetting to the default value and how to stop it? here is the code:

PHP:

```
$Sql = "SELECT Distinct Material,UnitMeasure,Price,Count FROM Tbl_Parts where ItemType ='Permit' ";
  $result = mysqli_query($conn, $Sql);

    echo "<table id='tablePerm1' class='content-table'>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<th>Permit</th>";
    echo "<th>Unit</th>";
    echo "<th>Price</th>";
    echo "<th>Amount</th></tr>";

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
      echo "<tr><td id = 'Mat'>";
      echo $row['Material'];
      echo "</td><td id = 'Unt'>";
      echo $row['UnitMeasure'];
      echo "</td><td id = 'Prc'>$";
      echo $row['Price']; 
      echo "</td><td id = 'Cnt' contenteditable = 'true'>";
      echo $row['Count']; 
      echo "</td></tr>";
      }
      echo "</table>";
```

HTML:

```
 <button id ="QAdd" onclick="MakeArray();">Add</button>
```

Javascript:

```
function MakeArray() {

var table = document.getElementById ("tablePerm1");

 var data = [];

  for (var i = 1; i < table.rows.length; i++){

    if (table.rows[i].cells[3].innerHTML = "0"){

    }else{

      for(var j = 0; j < table.rows[i].cells.length; j++){
          data.push(table.rows[i].cells[j].innerHTML);
        }

      }
  } 
alert(data);
};
```